# How do I make a timed function and use "ctx"? (Discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So I'm trying to make a timed function for my Discord bot with python.

So my function is as follows:

```
async def checkday(ctx):
    while(True):
        "code yada yada"
        if true:
            await ctx.send("hello")
        await asyncio.sleep(X)
```

and at the bottom:

```
bot.loop.create_task(checkday())
```

However, I either get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\philk\Desktop\Discord Bot\testrevbot.py", line 374, in <module>
    bot.loop.create_task(checkday())
TypeError: checkday() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'
```

So I'm assuming there is an argument I'm missing here:

```
bot.loop.create_task(checkday())
```

How would I be able to fix this? I'm using Rewrite I believe, so is there a way to send messages without Context?

EDIT: I want to, for example, run the loop in checkday() every 12 hours, and if conditions are met, then to send a message.

"https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/rewrite/examples/background_task.py" doesn't appear to work for me.

Comment: Here is an example of a background task with the rewrite version https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/rewrite/examples/background_task.py

Comment: What do you mean by a "timed function"?  What exactly do you expect this to do?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Where do you want to send the message to?

Comment: Probably a specific channel.

Comment: With the example, are you replacing the channel ID and token before running?

Answer (score -3):

If you are doing this in a cog, you are most probably missing `self` as the first argument.